# How do you change the name of a pyramid project?

Tags: python, pyramid

I am just starting out with pyramid and I am doing the tutorial. I would like to use some of the tutorial code as a starting point for the project that I am going to start, but I don't want to keep the project name as tutorial. It seems like once you give a project a name that name is used in many places. Is there a way to easily change the project name? I am sure I will have to manually edit some stuff. Just wondering if there may be an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a "project name". It's the name of a python package. Yes, you'll have to search/replace and rename that package everywhere in your code. You're probably better off just starting from a new project with the right name if you are only at the tutorial stage.

Comment: It'd be cool to have a command that renames the project.

Comment: @RobertGrant what you're asking for is a refactoring tool that can rename a python package including all import statements etc. Some IDEs support part of that but don't hold your breath on anything that does it for pyramid specifically.

Comment: Well I'd understand that I'd need to rename all the bits in my code etc (or yeah, an IDE refactor), I just mean the bits that Pyramid supplies in a scaffold.